# Grate that does not cause air rush noise?

Tags: acoustics

I have an air supply grate that is making a roaring noise. It has rectangular slats.

I know the sound is coming from the grate, not the duct, because when I remove the grate, the duct is silent. It is only when the grate is in place that it is noisy.

Is there a shape I can make a grate that will generate little or no noise when air passes through it?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a metal grate, the sound may be amplified by the grate itself vibrating, and possibly transferring the vibrations into the duct and then the structure of the building.

A plastic grate (if such a thing is available) may be quieter because the material has more internal damping than metal.

Comment: It is a solid wooden grate.

Answer (score 0):

You can try variable gravity adjusting horizontal slats.

They are hinged at the top and swing down, so as they can open more with larger air flow and hang shut when there is no flow.

Answer (score 0):

If the grate is designed to only prevent larger things getting through then using a mesh 1cm or 1/2 inch squares may be appropriate.